# generating random pair key has standard?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, wallet

If a crypto wallet generates all pair key between small range for example between 1-100, the risk and possibility of creating the same key is an increase. Generating random pair keys for cryptocurrency has standard? If the answer is No what the solution cryptocurrency for it?

Answer (score 1):

Developers of reputable wallets use a suitable source of randomness and will generate a key in the whole range available, not restricted to some arbitrary small range.

So far as I know there is no standard (e.g. BIP) that specifies this. It is assumed knowledge.

For example see https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-generate-your-very-own-bitcoin-private-key-7ad0f4936e6c/